# how to display content of variables of file1 to file2 in python

Tags: python, import

i want to display content of list of file1 to file 2 in python

I am just providing a sample code in that file1 have a list and a variable. I just wanted to display content of that list in file2 by importing. the code is giving an error

from file1 import list1,p

ImportError: cannot import name list1

my code is :

file1:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = ['a','b']
    p = 123
    print list1
    print p
```

file2:

```
from file1 import list1,p
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list2 = ['p','q']
    pb = 321
    print list2
    print pb
    print list1
    print p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file1, instead of having **`if __name__ == '__main__'`** you should use **`if __name__ == 'file1'`**. This is because when you are importing this file in file2, the `__name__` of file1 is **not** `__main__` instead it is the name of the file which is **`file1`**.

So, having something like this will help:

file1:

```
if __name__ == 'file1':
    list1 = ['a','b']
    p = 123
    print(list1)
    print(p)
```

file2:

```
from file1 import list1,p
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list2 = ['p','q']
    pb = 321
    print(list2)
    print(pb)
    print(list1)
    print(p)
```

Output, when running file2:

```
['a', 'b']
123
['p', 'q']
321
['a', 'b']
123
```

You can remove the brackets from the print statements as I am using Python3 instead of Python2.

But using `__name__ == 'file1'` is redundant in file1.

Answer (score 1):

in `file1` you have `if __name__ == '__main__':` but since `file1` is imported, that's not true in this case.  Perhaps something like this for `file` would be more appropriate:

```
list1 = ['a','b']
p = 123
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print list1
    print p
```

It seems that in your case the `print` statements are only there for debugging in the case that `file1` is invoked directly.  But `list1` and `p` must be defined to be imported, in which case the `print` statements probably aren't supposed to run (I'd assume from your code).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the if statement:

file1.py:

```
list1 = ['a','b']
p = 123
```

file2.py:

```
from file1 import list1,p
print(list1) #output: ['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make your list1 and p functions instead of just variables (see below):

**file1.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = ['a','b']
    p = 123
    print(list1)
    print(p)

def list1():
    list1 = ['a','b']
    print(list1)

def p():
    p = 123
    print(p)
```

And then in your second file call them like so:

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list2 = ['p','q']
    pb = 321
    print(list2)
    print(pb)
    list1()
    p()
```

You could also more simply just do this instead:

```
list1 = ['a','b']
p = 123
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(list1)
    print(p)
```

Hope this helps!